# REPLACE function with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I've inherited a project and I'm trying to update an existing query to include a new field. The query currently works but I'm adding a date field to it and this causes an error

The code is:

```
INSERT INTO AccountStorage WITH(TABLOCK) (Account_Id, Account_Number, Expiry_Date, userid, [timestamp])
    SELECT        
         REPLACE(AccountStorage_STAGING.Account_Id,'"','') Account_Id
        ,REPLACE(AccountStorage_STAGING.Account_Number,'"','') Account_Number
        ,REPLACE(AccountStorage_STAGING.Expiry_Date,'"','') Expiry_Date
        ,IE.userid 
        ,IE.lastruntime [timestamp]
    FROM  
        (SELECT userid, lastruntime
         FROM tblIEConfiguration 
         WHERE name = 'Account Storage Update') IE 
    CROSS JOIN 
        AccountStorage_STAGING 
    LEFT JOIN 
        AccountStorage ON AccountStorage_STAGING.Account_Id = AccountStorage.Account_Id
```

The column I'm now trying to add is the `Expiry_Date`, I assume this doesn't work as it's being treated as a string, I have tried multiple cast statements but I can't seem to get it to work. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Expiry_Date in both tables is a datetime field

The error is :

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What is the error message when you are executing the current query ? Please also include some sample data and schema for table `AccountStorage`

Comment: A `DATE` (or `DATETIME` / `DATETIME2(n)`) in SQL Server is a **binary** value - not a string - so you cannot apply `REPLACE` to it. You can however define how a date is being displayed, when you're outputting it. But here you're inserting it into another table - where it hopefully also is a `DATE` (or similar) datatype - so you really don't need to do any string formatting to it - just insert "as is"

Comment: "Expiry_Date in both tables is a datetime field" - so what are you hoping to get out of using `REPLACE` on it?